# Is showing google maps layer in OpenLayers legal?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, openlayers

Im reading Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service but Im not sure I clearly understand. It's in statement 10.2 a) . Is OpenLayers a wrapper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenLayers is considered a wrapper library.

However, when this clause was introduced to the Terms of Service (approximately a year ago), OpenLayers was granted a specific waiver.

You can read some additional discussion at http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-dev/2012-April/008625.html (and associated emails in that thread).

Comment: Also useful is the [official documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Google-js.html) for the Google Maps component. It links to a Nabble archive of the same discussion you link to.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the OpenLayers, actully uses the Maps API it should be legal.

(ie so OpenLayers is not accessing the content directly - bypassing the Maps API)

How the Maps API is loaded (that it loaded via OpenLayers) is not really an issue - of course as long as Openlayers doesnt interfere with the Maps API.

<strike>Openlayers itself is not a wrapper.</strike> (edit: see other answer)

Comment: Oh. Seems I misunderstood what 'wrapper' means in the context of the Maps API. Consider jlivni's answer more authoritive than mine!